# записать массив в файл dbf

Tags: php, массивы, запись, dbf

Подскажите как записать массив в файл dbf. Создаю массив:

```
$array = array(
    $number,
    $sum,
    $descr,
    $date,
);
```

Массив заполнен. Видно через print_r($array);

Пытаюсь записать:

```
if ($db) {
    dbase_add_record($db, array(
        $number,
        $sum,
        $descr,
        $date,
    ));   
    // dbase_close($db);
  }
```

но файл пустой. переменная $db объявлена Доступ к файлу есть. Структура организована. Спасибо.

Comment: Попробуйте включить показ ошибок и посмотреть на результат.

Comment: Может это поможет? `Количество элементов массива должно быть равно числу полей в базе данных, в противном случае dbase_add_record() не удастся выполнить`. [Источник](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.dbase-add-record.php)